# Update JList after removing items

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

I have a problem with the JList. Whenever i remove items from it, the list does not update it's appearance so items remain there and become uncheckable.

Here is code:

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

JList figureListBox = new JList(listModel);
figureListBox.setBounds(5, 20, 240, 300);
figureListBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
figureListBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
figureListBox.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
figureListBox.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
figureListBox.setVisibleRowCount(10);

JButton deleteFigureButton = new JButton("Delete");
deleteFigureButton.setBounds(5, 305, 240, 25);
deleteFigureButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(currentFigure != -1) {
            listModel.remove(currentFigure);
            currentFigure = -1;
        }
    }
});`
```

Repaint and revalidate doesn't work, as well as updateUI()

[Here is a screenshot of how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKw04.png)

Comment: did you ever update `currentFigure` to a value >= 0 ? And the whole `repaint` stuff shouldn't be necessary

Comment: `currentFigure` = checked index of list box. The point is that I forgot to mention that list does update after moving a window and selected item that should be removed remove.

Comment: Is this code running in the AWT event dispatch thread?  See [javax.swing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/.

Comment: Then try to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` although I don't understand why it doesn't work for you. For me it works as expected

Comment: I run my application with `invokeLater` from the `main()` method.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the NetBeans code -->

//set data to jlist

```
 public void setList() {

    String[] listData = {"list1", "list2", "list3", "list3", "list3", "list3", "list3", "list3"};
    jList1.setListData(listData);

}
```

//delete data from jlist

```
public String[] delList() {

    ListModel<String> beforDeleteDataList = jList1.getModel();
    String[] newDataList = new String[beforDeleteDataList.getSize() - 1];  
    int beforDeleteDataListIndex = 1;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < (beforDeleteDataList.getSize()); i++) {

            newDataList[i] = 
            beforDeleteDataList.getElementAt(beforDeleteDataListIndex);
            beforDeleteDataListIndex++;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
return newDataList;}
```

//delete button action

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    jList1.setListData(delList());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> list does update after moving a window.

Verify whether you call setVisible() after adding components to the JPanel(if using it).

Check this if it relates to your problem. 
[JPanel doesn't update until resize Jframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069807/jpanel-doesnt-update-until-resize-jframe)

Also post your full code.